# how can I write a case-insensitive find_by_email for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, case-insensitive

I found that if a user registers with an email and use a capital letter in their email when I do the following I get nil.

Example:

```
username = Dillan@example.com

params[:user][:email] = dillan@example.com


user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])

user.nil?
```

=>  true

How can I search for an email without the problems of case sensitivity or how an I write a find_by_email that is case insensitive?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If a user(say X) has an email 'Dillan@example.com', then

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["lower(email) =?", "dillan@example.com"])
```

should return the user X. I didnt replicate the situation but that is what I guess you essentially need to do.

Or, more better, use where instead of find as pointed out by @MrTheWalrus

```
User.where('lower(email) = ?', "dillan@example.com").first
```

Comment: I'd go with `User.where('lower(email) = ?', "dillan@example.com").first`, but the key point (using the SQL lower() function) is the same.

Comment: Thanks MrTheWalrus and prasvin. I used your answers and they worked great.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus - I will post that as answer too, if u dont mind. Thanks.
I hear using find is deprecated.