# Rails Active Record case insensitive find

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, find

Though in general I like case-sensitivity in my database, there are a few times I find it a pain. user_name and email are good examples of fields where I don't want to worry about the case--especially when searching.

It is easy enough to downcase a string before saving using something like:

before_save do
  self.email.downcase!
end

This way the user_name and emails are always saved in lower case. But what is the best way to find_by_user_name and find_by_email? I can of course remember to always downcase the string I am passing into those methods--but that doesn't seem very DRY.

I thought about overriding find_by_email and calling the original with super once I downcased the e-amail, but I didn't have any luck figuring that out.

So, what is the best way to do this?

PS I don't think related posts like this one ( [how can I write a case-insensitive find_by_email for Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963477/how-can-i-write-a-case-insensitive-find-by-email-for-rails-3) ) are trying to solve for the same problem. Custom sql here with "lower" would be ointless for me since I already have ensured all of those values are lower--it is the one coming in right now (probably from a form where the user entered it) which I need downcased.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case-insensitive search in Rails model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220423/case-insensitive-search-in-rails-model)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of these should be good:

```
def self.find_by_lower_email(email)
  User.find_by_email(email.downcase)
end
# OR
def self.find_by_email(email)
  User.find(:all, :conditions => ["email = lower(?)", email]) 
end
```

**Update**:

The find_by_... functions are actually non-existing ones. When you call one of them, the ActiveRecord::Base catches your call in the `method_missing` method, and if the name is well formatted (contains column names, etc) then the appropriate find method is created for the class. After that it will exist.

If you have a `find_by_email`, it will be called by default. If it calls `super`, that means that you try to call `ActiveRecord::Base.find_by_email`, which does not exists. The `missing_method` catches it, and creates (actually overwrites your) `find_by_email` implementation. That is why not good to call super there. If you use your own implementation for finding by email, like I wrote in the second part, then it will work splendidly.

Comment: Thanks Matzi, I like your suggestions and I'm going to implement the first one. Just curious would you recommend creating this new method rather than overriding find_by_email? To me overriding it seems nicer since it is natural to call find_by_email--but then I'm not sure how.

Comment: In rails 2.0 it was flawed, and when you called super, the missing_method overridden your find_by function, causing it worked only once. I don't know if it is corrected, but better to be safe than sorry. If you want to call find_by_email, then use my second option, that should work anyway.

Comment: Sorry, not following the last part you wrote "if you want to call find_by_email, then use my second option ...". In your second option aren't I still calling find_by_lower_email?

Comment: I mean the two parts of my function are two different implementations. The second one can be used if you call the function find_by_email.

Comment: awesome. thanks for the revision. i get it. I'm going to implement the second solution.

Comment: just remember for the second method offered: find_by_email returns one result normally, so you will need to call .first on the overwritten methods' array response if you want it to behave normally.

Answer (score 34):

With PostgreSQL you can do:

```
User.where("email ILIKE ?", email).first
```

Comment: is this vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: To be clear (for future readers), the version in the question is safe from SQL injection. The version in the comment isn't.

Comment: @Kevin the version of what, Rails? PostgreSQL?

Comment: @evanrmurphy It looks like there was an old comment that has since been deleted that I was referring to.

Comment: `User.find_by 'email ILIKE ?', email` is how Rubocop recommends this, using [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) instead of where.first.

Answer (score 12):

I did something like this:

```
def self.find_by_email(email)
  Member.find(:first, :conditions => ["lower(email) =?", email.downcase])
end
```

You can debate on if this is right or not, but generally email should PROBABLY be normalized going into the database to prevent the need to do this.

Edit:
Rails 3:

```
Member.where("lower(email) =?", email.downcase).first
```

Comment: either I am missing your point or you missed the point of my question. I agree that typically you should downcase before saving. If you assume that is done, you don't need the "lower(email) =?" part but you would still need the email.downcase part--since often the email address is supplied by the user and they may not have downcased--that was the point of my question. I believe Matzi's response is correct.

Comment: Well you should know if it is or is not downcased on insertion into the DB. It seems that Matzi's response is a great solution, but its making assumptions that the email is lowercased in the DB or is lowercased when passed into the find_by_email method, I believe. His also will return an array of emails, while :first will return the first response as the actual Member object. No?

Comment: you make a good point on :first. I don't think it is wrong though to assume that the e-mail is downcased in the solution since this is specifically noted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me! thank you, but with lower(:xxx).

Client.includes(:responsibles).where(["lower(name) || lower(contact) ||   cnpj || clients.rg || rg ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%"])